# Ignoring Tensorflow Logging Warnings

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorboard

I get the following warnings over and over again when I use tensorboard with Keras:

> W0117 12:16:23.279854 Reloader tf_logging.py:120] Found more than one
>   graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def,
>   as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the
>   newest event.
>
> W0117 12:16:23.279854 16108 tf_logging.py:120] Found more than one
>   graph event per run, or there was a metagraph containing a graph_def,
>   as well as one or more graph events.  Overwriting the graph with the
>   newest event.
>
> W0117 12:16:23.280850 Reloader tf_logging.py:120] Found more than one
>   metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest
>   event.
>
> W0117 12:16:23.280850 16108 tf_logging.py:120] Found more than one
>   metagraph event per run. Overwriting the metagraph with the newest
>   event.

I get why they're occurring but I don't want to clear the log files. I want to ignore all of these because they're not fatal and annoying. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to silence all the warnings, just set:

```
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
```

This way only `ERROR` messages will be printed.

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Messages still printed out like normal.